# Are there any pre-Lower Decks ships that we now know to have been California-class?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship, retcon, star-trek-lower-decks

According to the *Star Trek: Lower Decks* showrunner Mike McMahan,

> The ship is in great condition. It’s a California-class ship, which has always existed in Starfleet — [this is] what we’re saying — that they’re the utility support ships. In the California-class [line], there are three types of hull painting: there’s blue, red, and yellow.
>
> <sub><sup>[LOWER DECKS Roundup: McMahan Talks Cerritos Starship Design, Starfleet Recruitment Posters, and a New Visit to THE READY ROOM](https://blog.trekcore.com/2020/08/star-trek-lower-decks-roundup-cerritos-design-new-posters-ready-room/)</sup></sub>

This means that California-class ships were likely ubiquitous in the *The Next Generation*/*Deep Space Nine* era from an *in-universe* perspective. California-class ships likely frequently called at DS9, and many of the crew of the Enterprise-D and Voyager would likely have had service history on board a California-class ship at some point in their careers or at least encountered one.

To this end, are there any specific *pre-Lower Decks* ships that we now (with the release of *Lower Decks* and supporting material) know to have been California-class? To be clear, I'm looking for more evidence than "yes, they were there" and asking about specific ships, whether or not named. For example, a source indicating that one of the ships lost at Wolf 359 was California-class would count, even if the ship is not named, since we know there were at most [40-ish ships there](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/85966/70477) and not an indefinitely vague number. Likewise, a source indicating that the unseen but mentioned ship that Wesley returned to the Academy on in a specific episode was a Cali-class would count since it would be a specific ship that we already knew existed (we just didn't know what class it belonged to).

I do recognize that the California class was, out-of-universe, invented for the *Lower Decks* show. My question solely concerns *in-universe* matters and especially whether any previously mentioned (but unseen) ships have been reconned to California-class.

Comment: It may be better to read that as there has always been "support ships" rather than always specifically California class.

Comment: Might be worth looking for other ships named for small cities in the Los Angeles—Long Beach—Anaheim California Metropolitan Statistical Area.

Comment: "that we now know to have been Cali class": do you mean we would know this because the ship fulfilled a 'support' function? Or because we saw the ship on-screen and it looks like a California class? Because for the former it seems a bit a of stretch to assume that all support ships are always California class

Comment: *@MikeMcMahanTM - says the ship will be a new class call[ed] the California class that operates [as] a support ship. The #StarTrekLowerDecks ship will be called the U.S.S. Cerritos. #StarTrekSDCC* - https://mobile.twitter.com/StarTrekOnPPlus/status/1152659444326490112

Answer (score 5):

**Thus far, no ships in the existing Star Trek canon have been *revealed* to have been California class.**

Excepting the video games and the Lower Decks TV show ([for which the class was invented](https://mobile.twitter.com/StarTrekOnPPlus/status/1152659444326490112)), the sole mention of that ship-class within the Extended Universe has been in the novels [*Star Trek: Coda - The Ashes of Tomorrow*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Ashes_of_Tomorrow) and [*Star Trek: Coda - Oblivion's Gate*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Oblivion%27s_Gate), which introduces a new
California-class vessel not seen in Lower Decks.

> A second earlier, and he would have been in his seat next to Captain
> Hautuk, but the spatial shockwave that had slammed into the *Saticoy*
> came from out of nowhere, knocking the small California-class cruiser
> off its axis.

Answer (score 4):

There is a Memory Alpha  article for the California Class.

It [has a section](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/California_class#Ships_commissioned) listing all known ships of the class.

```
USS Alhambra
USS Cerritos (NCC-75567)
USS Merced (NCC-87075)
USS Rubidoux (NCC-12109)
USS Solvang (NCC-12101)
Unnamed California-class starships
```

All examples listed are from the show *Lower Decks*.

So, the answer to your question is no.